# OSGi Maven: missing requirement osgi.wiring.package

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, osgi

I have a problem with Maven OSGi app (in NetBeans).

I have a 3 OSGi bundles: `application`, `utils` and `view`.

- `application` imports `view`
- `view` imports `utils`

The app compiles fine, but when i want to run it, it does not with this output message:

```
Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.lib.view)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
```

Whole error msg:

```
[java] Auto-properties start: file:/C:/Users/volek/Desktop/library_parent/view/target/classes/ (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: file:/C:/Users/volek/Desktop/library_parent/view/target/classes/ - java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file)
[java] ERROR: Bundle org.lib.application [3] Error starting file:/C:/Users/volek/Desktop/library_parent/application/target/application-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.lib.application [3]: Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.lib.view)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
[java] Auto-properties start: file:/C:/Users/volek/Desktop/library_parent/utils/target/classes/ (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unable to cache bundle: file:/C:/Users/volek/Desktop/library_parent/utils/target/classes/ - java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file)
[java] org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle org.lib.application [3]: Unable to resolve 3.0: missing requirement [3.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.lib.view)(version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
[java]  at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
[java]  at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
[java]  at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1291)
[java]  at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:304)
[java]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Whole output: http://pastebin.com/KBWSXfCT

The strange thing is that when I do not use anything from `utils` in `view` (but keep the dependency) it runs fine (without the error).

Comment: The error says the org.lib.application bundle imports the package org.lib.view with the version range [1.0,2.0). Is there an installed bundle which exports the org.lib.view package using a version in that range?

Comment: Yes, there is. I am trying it on new clean projects. It started after Windows reinstall => new version of NetBeans (7.4).

Comment: I have uninstalled NetBeans 7.4 and installed 7.3.1 and it is working now. Not sure if the installation was just broken or whether there is a bug in 7.4.